# What is meant by stability in relation to neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I hear the terms stability/instability thrown around a lot when reading up on Deep Q Networks. I understand that stability is improved with the addition of a target network and replay buffer but I fail to understand exactly what it's refering to.

What would the loss graph look like for an instable vs stable neural network?

What does it mean when a neural network converges/diverges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Stability, also known as algorithmic stability, is a notion in
> computational learning theory of how a machine learning algorithm is
> perturbed by small changes to its inputs. A stable learning algorithm
> is one for which the prediction does not change much when the training
> data is modified slightly.

Here Stability means suppose you have 1000 training data that you use to train the model and it performs well. So in terms of model stability if you train the same model with 900 training data the model should still perform well , thats why it is also called as algorithmic stability.

As For the loss Graph if the model is stable the loss graph probably should be same for both size of training data (1000 & 900). And different in case of unstable model.

As in Machine learning we want to minimize loss so when we say a model converges we mean to say that the model's loss value is within acceptable margin and the model is at that stage where no additional training would improve the model.

Divergence is a non-symmetric metrics which is used to measure the difference between continuous value. For example you want to calculate difference between 2 graphs you would use Divergence instead of traditional symmetric metrics like Distance.